# Dynamic Prog Help (knapsack)

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm working on this Dynamic Programming problems, and I'm stuck on writing an iterative solution in Java

The goal is to find the minimum number of calories it takes to spend exactly X cents. If we cannot spend exactly X cents then there is no solution. We are given N the number of items, and each item has value V and calorie C attributed to it.

```
public static void iterative(int[] v, int[] c, String[] items, int X, int num_items)
{
    System.out.println("Iterative");

    int N = num_items;
    int[] min = new int[X];


    int i, j;
    for(i=1 i < X; i++) {
        min[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    min[0] = 0;
    for(i=1;i<=X;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            if(v[j]<=i && ((min[i-v[j]]+c[i]) < min[i])) //Wrong?
            {
                min[i] = min[i-v[j]] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I'm just not really understanding the recurrence relationship for the iterative steps.

Comment: are you clear with the knapsack algorithm. ?

Comment: Still pretty new to me, just been looking over http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem and other examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relationship will be the same, it doesn't matter if you are programming it top down or bottom up. Since you have looked upon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem the recurrence relation will remain the same. Only change is that in general in Knapsack problem you are given a limit (weight limit) and you are supposed to maximize the value in that limit. But since you want to spend exactly X cents, you need to check it specifically. I know this is java language specific question, but I wrote a C++ code. Java conversion should be pretty straight forward, I hope that helps.

```
#define INTMAX 1000000
int solve(int *v,int *c,int X,int n){
    int **result= new int * [n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        result[i]=new int[X+1];
    }
    //initialization with the first object. INTMAX shows it's not possible to find items in exactly X cents.
    for(int i=1;i<=X;i++){
        if(v[0]==i)
            result[0][i]=c[0];
        else
            result[0][i]=INTMAX;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=X;j++){
            // either you can choose ith object or leave it. Check explicitly for the case when you can't select items with X cents.
            result[i][j]=min((j>=v[i])?(c[i]+result[i-1][j-v[i]]):INTMAX, result[i-1][j]);
            cout<<"i:"<<i<<"\tj:"<<j<<"\tresult:"<<result[i][j]<<"\n";
        }
    }
    return result[n-1][X]==INTMAX?-1:result[n-1][X];
}
```

It returns -1 if its not possible to spend exactly X cents. Let me know if you need some more inputs in understanding. Although I would suggest using top-down approach for knapsack problem since you don't need to calculate all subproblems for any single problem.

Comment: Thanks @Naman I don't know much C but I put it together the best I could.

Comment: @Leroy No problem, I haven't Java for a long time otherwise I definitely would have put it in Java. But I guess the concept should be clear. If not please let me know, I'd happy to help.